# Do the existing/defined DALI protocol commands include color temp adjustment?

Tags: led, dali

I want to know if the officially defined DALI commands entail anything related to adjusting color temperature.

I understand that it specified quite a few commands in adjusting brightness, but I failed to find anything linked to color temp.

Am I correct in assuming it is entirely manufacture-specific?

I've spent quite a lot of time searching, but I can only land search hits with product pamphlets, and nothing remotely related to DALI packets sent and received over the DALI network.

Can someone give me a confirmation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is not manufacturer-specific, it was standardised in IEC 62386-209:2011 
Digital addressable lighting interface - Part 209: Particular requirements for control gear - Colour control (device type 8) 
https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/6965

This covers four colour control types:

- XY Coordinate
- Tc Colour Temperature using a Mirek scale
- Primary N    direct primary
- RGBWAF Red Green Blue White Amber Freecolour.

It is optional which of these types are implemented in a gear which supports part 209.